# how to decode string in base64 and keep it as string in c# asp.net4

Tags: c#-4.0, base64, asp.net-4.0, decode

I am try to write this stuff in c# asp.net 4 framework.
I have a String variable called u. it is base64 encode of another string.
now I need to decode it and get the original string, the problem is that decoding convert it to byte array.how can I convert it to string?

I tried
Convert.FromBase64String(u).toString() but it didn't help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base-64 could be an encoding of *anything*.  If you know it's an encoding of an ASCII string, you could do this:

```
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(u);
var text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

If it's an encoding of a Unicode string (you weren't specific), you could do this:

```
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(u);
var text = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```